# 'dist' folder visibility under git

Tags: git, bower

I have installed some lib via

```
bower install bower.json
```

it's ok, was created some files, and files which need for me in folder **dist**.
I push to remote server the folder. But when I had updated the project the folder dist was absent. This take error because, required lib is absent. I changed it on my working tree and files in **dist** folder exist on local machine, only when has beed done *bower install bower.json*.

So I don't understand why *.js in folder dist are unvisible for git, and I don't have possibility to push them.

files

```
*.js
*.min.js (that I use)
*.tar.gz
*.min.js.map
```

I think it take the problem on **prod** because I don't have possibility do bower *install bower.json*.

So the main question, why does the folder dist devoid of possibility to push files inherit?

Comment: is there a .gitignore file in your project?

Comment: yes, you are right. I removed dist from .gitignore and it's work well